# LibXL load file failure

Tags: c++, excel, xlsx, libxl

Here is the code to load the xls/xlsx file:

```
int main()
{ 
    BookHandle book = xlCreateBook();

    if(book) 
    {
        if(xlBookLoad(book, L"Slice.xlsx")) 
        {
            SheetHandle sheet = xlBookGetSheet(book, 0);
            if(sheet)
            {
                double d;
                const wchar_t* s = xlSheetReadStr(sheet, 2, 1, 0);

                if(s) wprintf(L"%s\n", s);

                d = xlSheetReadNum(sheet, 3, 1, 0);
                printf("%g\n", d);
            }
        }     

        xlBookRelease(book);
    }

    printf("\nPress any key to exit...");
    _getch();

    return 0;
}
```

These are actually the example code. the `xlBookLoad()` fails so that the if statement is skipped.

However, if I load its own file **example1.xls**, it succeeded.
**Slice.xlsx** and **example.xls** are in the same folder. I am 100% sure the file path is correct. It was the loading functionality that failed.

Now, I don't know why. Was that because the **Slice.xlsx** is kinda special? or LibXL is not the tool to load it? If so how can I read it?

I am attaching it here. Thanks a lot in advance to anyone that helps.

Slice.xlsx:

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/7949206/Slice.xlsx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the documentation, it is stated that you should use `xlCreateBook` to work with a *.xls file and `xlCreateXMLBook` to work with a *.xlsx file. Thus, for Slice.xlsx, use `xlCreateXMLBook` in the place of `xlCreateBook`. http://www.libxl.com/documentation.html